# Cant install WXWidgets in Ubuntu 16.06

Tags: wxwidgets

cant install WXWidgets from source (wxwidgets3.0-3.0.2.orig)

After configure which apparently runs without errors:

config.status: executing wx-config commands

Configured wxWidgets 3.0.2 for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

Which GUI toolkit should wxWidgets use?                 GTK+ 2 with support for GTK+ printing libnotify
  Should wxWidgets be compiled into single library?       no
  Should wxWidgets be linked as a shared library?         yes
  Should wxWidgets support Unicode?                       yes (using wchar_t)
  What level of wxWidgets compatibility should be enabled?
                                       wxWidgets 2.6      no
                                       wxWidgets 2.8      yes
  Which libraries should wxWidgets use?
                                       STL                no
                                       jpeg               builtin
                                       png                sys
                                       regex              builtin
                                       tiff               builtin
                                       zlib               sys
                                       expat              sys
                                       libmspack          no
                                       sdl                no

at Make I get this after a few lines:

ranlib /home/sem/Downloads/wxwidgets3.0-3.0.2.orig/lib/libwxregexu-3.0.a
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/jpeg/jcomapi.c', needed by 'wxjpeg_jcomapi.o'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `wxwidgets3.0-3.0.2.orig`, but this is not how the distribution archives are called, so it looks like you've got the file from which Ubuntu packages are built which doesn't seem to include the sources for 3rd party libraries such as libjpeg, presumably because these libraries are supposed to be already installed.

So you need to either install all the dependencies (you would find them in the `debian/control` file of the Ubuntu package) or get the really original sources from https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/v3.0.3 (there is no reason to use 3.0.2 when 3.0.3 is out).